# Visual studio 2010, Project changes lost

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I was developing in VS 2010, on my laptop with windows 8. And I didn't not shut down laptop(it was in Hibernate mode), close applications for 5 days but I had been saved every changes of my project in VS 2010. But recently the VS 2010 shows "Not Responding" message when I was working. And I tried to close it, so it asked permission to Restart Visual Studio. When I clicked Restart, my project has opened without last 5 days changes!
I've searched about project history, but in VS 2010 that isn't exists.
How to reopen project with last 5 days changes?
Help please!

Comment: Have you tried to contact MS support? 
You got trouble using one of their products, running it on another of their products. If yes what did they told you?

Comment: Have you actually lost code, e.g. you wrote a line of code in a class file and the file still exists but the line has gone? Or, are files missing from the solution but present on the hard drive? What I'm getting at is, are you sure its not just the solution or project files which are not up to date? Those should be fairly trivial to recreate.

Comment: Actually a lot might have happened. Please provide us with more information this is a very general thing. The best thing we can do is start guessing. Best shot though is describe what happended on MS support.

Comment: @StephenKennedy I lost my code changes, created files, class files etc., everything which I have created last 5 days. That was so much labor and work. I just want today's version of my project, instead of 5 days ago. What do you mean?

Comment: Ok let's start from the begining. Just calm down and tell me please, you made a project. You created some files. Then you changed those files by adding code right?
The whole pack of your app development on V Studio is called solution.
Do you have the solution? Does it exists?
Or is the whole solution missing?

Comment: @GeorgeEco You know "Not Responding", it just happened to VS 2010. And I clicked X button to try close the Window. And Message Window showed question with 3 or 4 optional answer, such like "Which one would you prefer", 1.Restart VS 2010 2.Close VS 2010 3.Report the Issue to MS. I didn't really remember what actually those answers was. Then clicked Restart one, so VS 2010 shows my project which I opened 5 days ago. I think the worst thing i've ever done is didn't close VS 2010 for 5 days.

Comment: Okay. Your project should be saved on a folder. Right?
Can you find that folder by browsing your file system?
Check if you can open the project from there. It might have "restored" the 5 days ago project replacing the current, but it might have a different behaviour opening if grom file system.

Comment: Solution, and it's project is still there now. I just lost the changes of last 5 days.

Comment: In any case this is weird, annoying and you must report it to MS support. Actually, are you SURE you did saved your project? Check for all your VS projects. Maybe there is a different "version" of your solution there.

Comment: I opened solution from it's folder, but it was same as the VS crashes opened solution. Last 5 days I had created several files into the solution, i remember i was showing them. but now i the created files are missing?

Comment: Neither solution contains your 5 days work I suppose....
sorry man, can't imagine what happened. Seems like a rare bug to me. But can't give you a solid answer. :(

Comment: I'm still not convinced you lost CODE and not (trivial) changes to .csproj or .sln. PLEASE if not done already, open the folder in Explorer and look at the code files in a text editor such as Notepad or Notepad++. If indeed you DID lose code I'm really sorry to hear that :(

Comment: (My rationale is that in Visual Studio, the Save button saves the current item; Save All - a different button - saves everything. Often I find I think I have saved everything but press Save All and tortoisesvn shows me a new diff in a .csproj or .sln. If the OP has been pressing save - on every file of course - but not save all he shouldn't have lost code changes).

Comment: @StephenKennedy, Thank you too to try solve my issue, but now I lost my changes. Then I think I should redo my works now. I appreciate your answers that I tried. Best regards, and beware of this problem. :)